# Не может обработать xml

Tags: php, xml, 1с

ДД,

Интегрирую 1С,

Получаю XML файл, около 400 товаров,

Надо отобразить товар в определенных складах,
в тэге каждого товара имеются склады.

```
<Товары>
  <Товар>
    <Cклад ИдСклада="213123123123" Количество="1">
    <Cклад ИдСклада="213123123122" Количество="2">
  <Товар>
  <Товар>
    <Cклад ИдСклада="213123123123" Количество="1">
    <Cклад ИдСклада="213123123122" Количество="2">
  <Товар>
  <Товар>
    <Cклад ИдСклада="213123123123" Количество="1">
    <Cклад ИдСклада="213123123122" Количество="2">
  <Товар>
</Товары>
```

Проблема в том что складов около 100-а.

И нужно пройтись по тегам что отсортировать определенные.

Обрабатывает всё это простой php файл (вызываемый AJAXом):

```
foreach ($xml->Товары->Товар as $value){
   foreach ($value->Склад->attributes() as $c => $b) {
       echo $c.' : '.$b.'<br>';
   }
}
```

Когда работаю на малом количестве товаров всё работает.
На основном файле, нет.

Как правильно сделать?

При отправке частями 1С умирает, поэтому передаю одним файлом.

Как разбить XML на части?

---

```
foreach ($xml->ПакетПредложений->Предложения->Предложение as $value) {
            $price = $value->Цены->Цена->ЦенаЗаЕдиницу;
            $remnants = $value->Количество;
            ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
            foreach ($value->Склад as $value2){
                foreach ($value2->attributes() as $c => $b) {
                    echo $c.' : '.$b.'<br>';
                }
            }
}
```

Вот реальный кусок кода php

А xml товара слишкоом большой, что бы его здесь разместить

Comment: Откуда `Товары->Товар` ? если в примере `XML` только `Товар` - уважайте время других, и предоставляйте достоверную информацию.

Comment: *Как разбить XML на части?* Лечить надо не симптомы, а болезнь. Разбирайтесь, почему на основном файле не работает - скорее всего, как сказал предыдущий оратор, иная структура.

Comment: @DigitalCore Ошибочка там товар родительский тэг еще имеется, спсибо поправил

Comment: @Akina Он на это м файле работает если я циклом склады не перебираю, но мне надо пройтись по всем складам и получить их аттрибуты

Comment: Не могли бы Вы максимально точно определить, что в Вашем понимании означает выражение "не работает"? PHP как-то не замечен в невыполнении/пропуске операторов...

Comment: И ещё - в реальном файле так и идёт Товар-Товар-Товар? или там всё же что-то вроде Топоры-Пилы-Лапти?

Comment: @Akina Я подробнее сейчас отредактирую вопрос

Comment: `$value->Слад` точно там `слад` а не `склад`?

Comment: @teran в попыхах ошибся, но всё равно не работает

Comment: `foreach ($value->Слад as $value2)` откуда здесь `$value2` и `Слад`

Comment: вас просили объяснить, "что значит не работает", пока суть проблемы вашей не ясна. какой результат вы получаете, и какой ожидаете

Comment: @DigitalCore Просто в начале я показал упрощенную схему, сам xml файл отобразить не могу так как лимит символов, даже товар выбивается с лимита.

Comment: @teran у файла более 100000 строк, и два очень ёмких цикла, просто мощностей не хватает обработать этот файл, как мне разгрупировать этот файл или его обработку

Comment: @MaksatSh 1). сделайте отдельный файл на каждый склад. У вас изначально провальная структура, 2). сделайте родительскими тегами склады -> склад->отдел->категория->товар в таком случае каждый склад можно обработать в отдельном потоке - что уменьшит нагрузку, и увеличит скорость.

Comment: @MaksatSh дак вот с этого и начинайте описание проблем. 400 товаров изначально вами обозначенных явно не тянут на 100к строк. мы по вашему догадываться об этом должны? Используйте SAX парсеры как вариант, DOM на таких объемах если и будут работать, то явно не быстро.

Comment: А как насчет CSV? Просто, как железная дорога, наглядно, легко обрабатывать на обоих сторонах.